# How to stop the "force close" error

Tags: java, android

Iam giving some Values in EditText,but if i try to delete it using backspack button and to enter new value..It is getting ForceClosed.How to Rectify this Problem

My code is given below

```
empty_cyl_recvd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.empty_cyl_recvd);
 new_cyl_recvd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.new_cyl_recvd);
 filled_cyl_unload = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.filled_cyl_unload);`enter code here`
  dmg_cyl_recvd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dmg_cyl_recvd);      

     total_dmg_cyl=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.sdff);
    total_empty_cyl=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.wertyu);    
    total_filled_cyl=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.gfhgftg);

 empty_cyl_recvd.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
         {

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                    int arg2, int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {

    int a=Integer.parseInt(empty_cyl_recvd.getText().toString());             int b=Integer.parseInt(Util.EMPTY_LIST.get(0).toString());
                int c=a+b;
                total_empty_cyl.setText(""+c);


                            }});

         filled_cyl_unload.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
         {

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {

                int a=Integer.parseInt(filled_cyl_unload.getText().toString());
                int b=Integer.parseInt(Util.FILL_LIST.get(0).toString());
                int c=a+b;
                total_filled_cyl.setText(""+c);


         });


         dmg_cyl_recvd.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {

                int a=Integer.parseInt(dmg_cyl_recvd.getText().toString());
                int b=Integer.parseInt(Util.DAMAGE_LIST.get(0).toString());
                int c=a+b;
                                total_dmg_cyl.setText(""+c);


         });``
```

Comment: Add empty check for all EditText before parsing into integer in onTextChanged.

Comment: What you want to achieve? Want to filter something?

Comment: to stop force close put onTextChanged() code inside try{}catch(){} block.

Comment: look at the android log first to figure out why you are getting the force close, if null pointer then check for empty edittexts before doing any action. If some other error, figure out whats wrong in the code thats causing the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st of all i would suggest you to use debugger, that would help you catch such issues quickly.

in the code of onTextChange there are possibility of exceptions (NPE/NumberFormat/ArrayIndexOutOfBounds). So to put appropriate check around this code

```
int a,b;
if(dmg_cyl_recvd.getText() != null && !dmg_cyl_recvd.getText().trim().equals("")) // also put it in try-catch for the case the input is not numeric
try{
    a=Integer.parseInt(dmg_cyl_recvd.getText().toString());
}catch(NumberFormatException ex){
//alert user about wrong input
}
if(Util.DAMAGE_LIST.size() > 0)//assuming it is a list, if not use method that gives the size of corresponding collection
    b=Integer.parseInt(Util.DAMAGE_LIST.get(0).toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Add proper exception handling to avoid Forced Close. You are probably getting NumberFormatException on Integer.parseInt(..) when it gets empty/invalid text.